# Tensorflow Keras Predict Returning Wrong Shaped Output

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, resnet

I am trying to predict a single image. But my model returns a prediction array with the shape (1,1,1,2048) when it should be (1,10). Any idea what I am doing wrong? My x input shape is correct at (1,32,32,3).

```
ResNet50V2(): 
  IMG_SHAPE = (32, 32, 3)
  return tf.keras.applications.ResNet50V2(input_shape=IMG_SHAPE, include_top=False, weights=None, classes=10)

model = ResNet50V2()
x = x[None, :]
predictions = model.predict(x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are loading your keras-model with parameter

```
include_top=False
```

which cuts of the fully-connected projection layer that is responsible for projecting the model output to your expected amout of classes. Change the parameter to True.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are disabling top with the include top, which removes the final classification layer. You need to either add your own layer with 10 classes or remove the include top parameter and retrain the network with the desired inputs.

Answer (score 0):

A image classification network usually works within 2 steps of processing.
The first one is feature extraction, we call that "base", and it consists in a stack of layers to find and reinforce patterns on image(2DConv, Relu and MaxPool).
The second one is the "head" and it is used to classify the extracted features from previous step.
Your code is getting the raw output of the "base", with no classification, and as the other gentle people stated, the solution is adding a custom "head" or changing the include_top parameter to True.